# Using Regular Expression Match a String that contains numbers letters and dashes

Tags: c#, regex, .net-3.5

I need to match this string `011Q-0SH3-936729` but not `345376346` or `asfsdfgsfsdf`
It has to contain characters AND numbers AND dashes

Pattern could be `011Q-0SH3-936729` or `011Q-0SH3-936729-SDF3` or `000-222-AAAA` or `011Q-0SH3-936729-011Q-0SH3-936729-011Q-0SH3-936729-011Q-0SH3-936729` and I want it to be able to match anyone of those. Reason for this is that I don't really know if the format is fixed and I have no way of finding out either so I need to come up with a generic solution for a pattern with any number of dashes and the pattern recurring any number of times.

Sorry this is probably a stupid question, but I really suck at Regular expressions.

TIA

Comment: Does the pattern always have a dash in the fifth and tenth index in the string?

Comment: Do we know how many dashes? Are there always regular sized groups of letters/numbers between the dashes? Letters as in A-Z? ...or a larger slice of the character set?

Comment: are dashes in a fixed position or can they be anywhere? (ROFL... I was too slow :)

Comment: Dashes could be anywhere and there could be any number of dashes.

Comment: Even at the very ends of the string?

Comment: Pattern could be 011Q-0SH3-936729 or 011Q-0SH3-936729-SDF3 or 000-222-AAAA or 011Q-0SH3-936729-011Q-0SH3-936729-011Q-0SH3-936729-011Q-0SH3-936729 and I want it to be able to match anyone of those. Reason for this is that I don't really know if the format is fixed and I have no way of finding out either so I need to come up with a generic solution for a pattern with any number of dashes and the pattern recurring any number of times

Comment: I think its safe to assume that there wont be any dashes at the start or end of the string, but no need really to cater for it. The text I'm matching to should't contain any dashes any where else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, 
    @"^             # Start of the string
    (?=.*\p{L})     # Assert that there is at least one letter
    (?=.*\p{N})     # and at least one digit
    (?=.*-)         # and at least one dash.
    [\p{L}\p{N}-]*  # Match a string of letters, digits and dashes
    $               # until the end of the string.", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

should do what you want. If by letters/digits you meant "only ASCII letters/digits" (and not international/Unicode letters, too), then use

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, 
    @"^             # Start of the string
    (?=.*[A-Z])     # Assert that there is at least one letter
    (?=.*[0-9])     # and at least one digit
    (?=.*-)         # and at least one dash.
    [A-Z0-9-]*      # Match a string of letters, digits and dashes
    $               # until the end of the string.", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: this will match strings like `-0-A-` (with leading and trailing dashes)

Comment: No I did not, but I did mention it wasn't nessacary to cater for them if it is the case. If there are dashes in that string as long as they form part of the same string that's fine. This works perfectly for what I needed. Thanks Tim, You are a genius. And thanks for explaining your regex and how it works, you deserve a +1 for that, I've learned a few things today.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**

this will match any of the key provided in your comments:

```
^[0-9A-Z]+(-[0-9A-Z]+)+$
```

this means the key starts with the digit or letter and have at leats one dash symbol:

Comment: See my two extra comments on the question above

Comment: This matches `A-A` or `0-0` (see the second sentence of the question).

Answer (score 0):

Most naive implementation EVER (might get you started):

```
([0-9]|[A-Z])+(-)([0-9]|[A-Z])+(-)([0-9]|[A-Z])+
```

Tested with [Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/).

EDIT:

That does match only three groups; here another, slightly better:

```
([0-9A-Z]+\-)+([0-9A-Z]+)
```

Comment: Hehe, yeah naive indeed :) See my two extra comments on the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info about the regularity of the dashes or otherwise, this is the best we can do:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input,@"[A-Z0-9\-]+\-[A-Z0-9]")
```

Although this will also match -A-0

Answer (score 0):

Are you applying the regex to a whole string (i.e., validating or filtering)?  If so, Tim's answer should put you right.  But if you're plucking matches from a larger string, it gets a bit more complicated.  Here's how I would do that:

```
string input = @"Pattern could be 011Q-0SH3-936729 or 011Q-0SH3-936729-SDF3 or 000-222-AAAA or 011Q-0SH3-936729-011Q-0SH3-936729-011Q-0SH3-936729-011Q-0SH3-936729 but not 345-3763-46 or ASFS-DFGS-FSDF or ASD123FGH987.";

Regex pluckingRegex = new Regex(
    @"(?<!\S)         # start of 'word'
      (?=\S*\p{L})    # contains a letter
      (?=\S*\p{N})    # contains a digit
      (?=\S*-)        # contains a hyphen
      [\p{L}\p{N}-]+  # gobble up letters, digits and hyphens only
      (?!\S)          # end of 'word'
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

foreach (Match m in pluckingRegex.Matches(input))
{
  Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

output:

```
011Q-0SH3-936729
011Q-0SH3-936729-SDF3
000-222-AAAA
011Q-0SH3-936729-011Q-0SH3-936729-011Q-0SH3-936729-011Q-0SH3-936729
```

The negative lookarounds serve as 'word' boundaries: they insure the matched substring *starts* either at the beginning of the string or after a whitespace character (`(?<!\S)`), and *ends* either at the end of the string or before a whitespace character (`(?!\S)`).

The three positive lookaheads work just like Tim's, except they use `\S*` to skip whatever precedes the first letter/digit/hyphen.  We can't use `.*` in this case because that would allow it to skip to the next word, or the next, etc., defeating the purpose of the lookahead.